# AMD Catalyst 13.9 installation failure

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers

Earlier today I installed Windows 8.1, and when I wanted to go into Catalyst Control Center, I noticed some odd error of CCC not being able to display options. I then figured I needed a driver update, so I downloaded the latest drivers, version 13.9, and tried to install them.

While it was trying to install the display drivers, I got a blue screen. Tried again and got the same. Then I used an uninstall tool from AMD to remove all traces of my old drivers and tried to install the new drivers. Again, a blue screen.

This is all I could think of to try. Would anyone know some other things I can try?

**EDIT:** thought I might want to include the log entry for the crash:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WER-SystemErrorReporting" Guid="{ABCE23E7-DE45-4366-8631-84FA6C525952}" EventSourceName="BugCheck" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="16384">1001</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-10-19T20:59:25.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>26587</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Simon-PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">0x0000007e (0xffffffffc0000005, 0xfffff80002a86dca, 0xffffd00025f250e8, 0xffffd00025f248f0)</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP</Data> 
  <Data Name="param3">101913-8953-01</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**Another edit:**

<del>As it turns out, the graphics card isn't showing up any more in the device manager. But as far as I can tell, it is still working (the fans are spinning and my screen is plugged into that graphics card).</del>

This is solved. it appears that my graphics card is now running with a default windows driver.

I also tried the forced method mentioned here: [AMD Graphics Drivers won't install properly](https://superuser.com/questions/591953/amd-graphics-drivers-wont-install-properly?rq=1) . But I still get a BSOD.

**Third edit:**
Slight succes! Managed to install version 13.4. Everything appears to be working fine now. I think I'm just going to skip version 13.9.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't install 13.9 on my system. The display driver always fails. AMD used to have good drivers, now they're just pumping out trash.