# Unable to install legacy AMD display drivers for Ati HD 3600 in Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-8.1, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

So, here is my problem. I have an **AMD HD 3600** card in my desktop and I wanted to install the official display driver from AMD (version *13.1* stable, or *13.4* beta, both had the same results). The drivers are the x64 version, just like my OS.
I followed the installation and everything appeared to be ok other than a warning when the installation gave a **completion** error. In all repetitions the install manager can install everything other than the actual display driver which always fails.
This occurred multiple times, even though I had the install manager **remove everything from AMD**, including itself, always followed by cleaning up via the often recommended [Driver Sweeper](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/4266-driver-sweeper.html).
Upon further inspection I realized, through the device manager, that Windows has a weird tendency to try and install the MS WDDM drivers for my GPU. While reading various sources, including [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/591953/amd-graphics-drivers-wont-install-properly) I tried uninstalling+deleting those, again through the device manager. Doing so resulted in the card and the "Display Adapters" group disappearing from the dev. manager and the resolution becoming significantly lower.
*(I should mention that if I attempt to install the AMD display drivers at this point,no matter the previous status of the AMD software, the Display Driver entry simply **does not appear** in the installer, only the rest of the stuff included in the package.)*
Following a reboot the group is there again but instead there is only the "Microsoft basic display card" element. At this point the system is heavily slowed down and within a few minutes the screen flickers as the OS has reinstalled the aforementioned WDDM drivers, getting me back to square one.

Is there a way for me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 by default tends to automatically install Microsoft drivers for hardware that doesn't seem to have any available. This appears to be problematic in your case so you need to disable this feature by following the directions in [this article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/stop-windows-7-from-installing-drivers-automatically).
Upon doing so, you can try to uninstall the MS drivers from the device manager utility as you described, followed by a reboot if there is no adapter at all there. After that, there should be a "Microsoft Basic display card" as you described. Run the latest catalyst package that is available for your card. You will notice that the setup proceeds to unpack the contents into the `C:/AMD/` directory by default. When the actual installer appears you may cancel it as the "display driver" module checkbox will not be available, as you said.
However you now have all the contents of the package extracted in the aforementioned folder. Go to Device Manager, right click the Basic Display Adapter > Update Driver Software. From this window you have the option to specify a certain driver where the driver software. Since you have already removed the MS drivers at this point and the OS won't be attempting to install them again thanks to the first step you took. Pick `C:/AMD` and let Windows search and install the AMD drivers that are extracted there. They should be installed and your cards will be displayed in the device manager as "ATI Radeon HD 3600 Series" while running its official manufacturer drivers.
Enjoy.